# Is the way to refresh widget with it's key in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

here is the widget I use it as the function  to refresh my widgets (it is usually a floating button with onpressed capability), so I want to use key of my widget in here to refresh my widget

```dart
Widget floatingButton(int index){
    if(index == 0){
        return FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(29, 142, 41,1),
            disabledElevation: 12,
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: () { 
                prefix0.Dashboard k = new prefix0.Dashboard();
                k.createState().reassemble();
            });
        }
    else return null;
}
```

and this is my widget which I want to refresh it, with its key **"refresh"**  in the future builder

```dart
FutureBuilder(
    key: refrKey,
    future: model.tData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Center(
                    child: Column(children: [
                        SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,),
                        Text('no data')
                     ]));
            } else { ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I already got an answer ;
`

```
 onPressed: () { 
        Navigator.push(    context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => this.build(context)));
   },
```

`
instead of using **setState()** which is not working as I want ,I rebuild the whole widget by call itself again and hance it get refreshed

Comment: I see you are pushing the page on navigator stack , so once you hit the back button or pop the screen you'll come back to the same page as it will have two copies of page on the stack. If that's what is helping you then using pushReplacement should work

Answer (score 0):

The `setState()` method will initiate re-render the UI widget for whom the state actually belongs to. the `setState()` method does not initiate re-render whole UI as @Omi said. You can refer to the official article about [Adding interactivity to your app](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive). If you've managed the state correctly, it should reflect in UI automatically upon `setState()` call.

Comment: nop, setstate() not respond well as I intended check the solution below work well for me

Answer (score 0):

You don't refresh a widget. If, for instance, you want to change the text on the button, you use a string variable to hold the text and you change that variable in a `setState`. The system will do the rest.